Помогите с реализацией графики для приложения в WindowsForms
Есть задание

Осуществлять продажу  изданий магазинам; Обеспечить наличие в одном заказе разных изданий в заданном количестве;

Мне не понятно как расставить компоненты на окне. Не могли нарисовать как будут выглядить компоненты на окне. Я использую БД pubs.
ДИАГРАММА БД pubs:

На данный момент я только добавил компоненты на форму:

Получается мне нужно три таблицы titles stores sales
И вот такой запрос:
INSERT INTO sales (stor_id, ord_num, ord_date, qty, payterms, title_id)
VALUES (@stor_id, @ord_num, @ord_date, @qty, @payterms, @title_id);

ОБНАВЛЕННАЯ ФОРМА:


Здесь не выполняют задания за вас. Здесь вы выполняете задание, а мы по возможности помогаем. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте то, что вы пытались реализовать самостоятельно, укажите, с какими именно проблемами столкнулись и где есть вопросы.

@aepot Значит я плохо объяснил. Я не хотел что бы за меня задания делали, я хотел что бы мне просто графически показали как это может выглядить. Это то что мне не понятно. Я сейчас тогда отредактирую попробую что нибудь до вставить.

@aepot Привет! Можете посмотреть и дать ответ

Это может выглядеть вот так, во всяком случае для указанного условия

Label, ComboBox, DataGridView и 2xButton.
Левую колонку можно с помощью комбобокса задать, правую через NumericUpDown. Но это уже на ваш вкус и цвет. Колонки "Цена" и "Сумма", судя по структуре БД тоже не помешали бы.

Спасибо большое за ответ! Смотрите вы писали про "Цену" и "Сумму", сумму вы имели ввиду уже когда я выберу издание и кол-во и уже итоговая сумма, это и есть сумма? И еще как можно красиво для изданий рядом их цену вывести? И последнее зачем кнопка отмена?

@AslanPAPA не, вы можете их добавить и посчитать прямо в этой таблице. Накладные на товары когда-нибудь видели?

То есть сперва я выбираю магазин, издание и кол-во, а потом внизу у меня будет datagrid где у меня будет таблица вроде накладной на товар (товар, кол-во, цена, сумма). И еще смотри может тупой вопрос, но когда я выбираю кол-во изданий то где в БД написано кол-во этого издания? ytd_sales это оно и есть?

@AslanPAPA без понятия, это же ваша бд

Не знаете как можно красиво вывести в ComboBox список задания или что то еще ?

@AslanPAPA если а вас есть новый вопрос, лучше детально задать его отдельно.
